# Exclude document URL from full text search Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-search

I am building a custom search application for Sharepoint 2013 (self-hosted). When performing a full-text search, the document URL should **not** be taken into account. For me, the URL of the document is not only irrelevant, but the search results are also misleading. E.g. if the user performs a keyword search which includes any part of the URL, ALL documents are returned.

To solve this, the URL should

- either not be crawled at all **OR**
- excluded from the full text search.

Is there any way to achieve this?

I see the following response on  Office 365, which relates to *Sharepoint Online* -
https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/400899 . 
apparently it is not possible there. Is this also true for self-hosted sites? If yes, could you think of a possible workaround?

Thanks

Comment: by "self-hosted" you mean *not* Sharepoint online?

Comment: yes, exactly. Not Sharepoint online